# A large numpy array re-arrangement

Tags: numpy

I have data in numpy array of the following shape:

```
import numpy as np

(128L, 512L, 4L, 9L)
```

How can I convert it into:

```
(36L, 128L, 512L)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reshape the array you could use:

```
arr.reshape(36, 128, 512)
```

but note that this might not place the values in the order you intend since,
per the [np.reshape docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html),

> You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array (using the
>   given index order), then inserting the elements from the raveled array
>   into the new array using the same kind of index ordering as was used
>   for the raveling.

Given the original shape, to preserve the 128 and 512-lengthed axes, you might
be looking for

```
arr.reshape(128, 512, 36).transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

or (equivalently)

```
np.rollaxis(arr.reshape(128, 512, 36), -1)
```

instead.

---

For example, if your original array is

```
arr = np.arange(128*512*4*9).reshape(128,512,4,9)
```

then

```
arr.reshape(128, 512, 36).transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

yields a new array of shape `(36, 128, 512)`:

```
>>> arr.reshape(128, 512, 36).transpose(2, 0, 1).shape
(36, 128, 512)
```

---

To see the difference between `arr.reshape(36, 128, 512)` and `arr.reshape(128, 512, 36).transpose(2, 0, 1)`, I encourage you to play with a smaller array in an interactive interpreter:

```
In [61]: arr = np.arange(2*2*3*4).reshape(2,2,3,4)

In [62]: arr
Out[62]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]],


       [[[24, 25, 26, 27],
         [28, 29, 30, 31],
         [32, 33, 34, 35]],

        [[36, 37, 38, 39],
         [40, 41, 42, 43],
         [44, 45, 46, 47]]]])
```

Suppose you want to preserve the axes of length 2, and reshape the other axes into a single axis of length 12.

If you use `arr.reshape(12,2,2)` then the **original** axes of length 2 are not preserved, in the sense that the values in those axes will have changed. For example, the values in

```
In [70]: arr[0,0,...]
Out[70]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

do not correspond to the values in

```
In [66]: arr.reshape(12,2,2)[:,0,0]
Out[66]: array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44])
```

but they do correspond to the values in

```
In [68]: arr.reshape(2,2,12).transpose(2, 0, 1)[:,0,0]
Out[68]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

just in a different shape.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But sorry, my original array shape is: (180L, 128L, 512L, 4L, 9L). I want to convert it into (180L, 36L, 128L, 512L). Is this correct: arr.reshape(180, 128, 512, 36).transpose(2, 0, 1)?

Comment: You would want `arr.reshape(180, 128, 512, 36).transpose(0, 3, 2,
1)`. The `(0, 3, 2, 1)` means "take the 0th axis, then the 3rd, 2nd, 1st".